# jquery form validation user have select minimum one field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made the following form and now want to write some code for validation which ensures users have selected a minimum of one field from all the fields. How can I achieve this?

```
<script>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get" id="myForm">
<label><b>Status:</b></label>
<select name="status" id="status">
  <option value="Active">Active</option>
  <option value="InActive">InActive</option>
</select><br>
<label><b>Type:</b></label>
<select name="type" id="type">
  <option value="Single">Single</option>
  <option value="Multiple">Multiple</option>
</select><br>
<label><b>Min Bed:</b></label>
<select name="min_bed" id="min_bed">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select><br>
<label><b>Max Bed:</b></label>
<select name="max_bed" id="max_bed">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You're jQuery/JS code is missing...

Comment: You an use a global var selection = 0 and then set to 1 inside .change metod of any object in the form.

Comment: @OfirBaruch i actually lol'ed

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the [jQuery validation plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) as follows.

Add this *jquery* code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myForm').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    rules: {
        status: {
            required: true,
        },
        type: {
            required: true,
        },
        min_bed: {
            required: true,
        },
        max_bed: {
            required: true,
        }
    }
});
```

} );

And yes don't forget to include necessary jquery files. Like *jquery.validate.js*

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>    
        $(document).ready(function () {        
        var select =0;        
        $('#status').change(function() {
              select =1
        })        
</script>
```

do .change for each object in your form ....

If you change at least one you will have the var select = 1